# EncodeURIComponent on ISOString using ngResource

Tags: angularjs, escaping, iso, ngresource, encodeuricomponent

I use ngResource for communicating with a RESTful api which takes in some date parameters. The date parameters are strings formatted to the ISO format.

When I use encodeURIComponent on these parameters, I see on my Fiddler that the colons are incorrectly escaped. Instead of %3A I see %253A.

```
myMod.factory('DateQuery', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return function (date1) {
        return $resource(
            '../api/datedata?date1=:date1', {
                date1: date1
            },
            {
            });
    }
}]);
```

And here is how I use it:

```
        var theDate = Date.now().toISOString();
        var escapeDate = encodeURIComponent(theDate);
        var promise = DateQuery(escapeDate).query().$promise;
        promise.then(function (data) { // do stuff });
```

If I look at the code in debug, I see that `escapeDate` is equal to `2016-05-04T19%3A00%3A00.000Z` as expected.

However when I observe this on Fiddler, I see:

```
GET /api/datedata?date1=2016-05-04T19%253A00%253A00.000Z
```

Where is this %25 coming from and how can I prevent this?

Comment: looks like it's encoding the % again.  %25 = %

Comment: Yes that's what I thought, but how can I prevent this?

Comment: try not doing the encoding yourself.  remove this line: var escapeDate = encodeURIComponent(theDate); and pass theDate into DateQuery

Comment: I had this initially, in this case it is not encoded at all and I see colons in the date params.